# Compare two lines using second columns

Tags: linux, text-processing, numeric-data

```
http://0-0.latam.corp.yahoo.com/                                      6656

http://0-0.latam.corp.yahoo.com/nonEtAk                               6670

http://1.avatar.yahoo.com/                                            6644

http://1.avatar.yahoo.com/nonEtAk                                     6858
```

Here the first column lists urls and second column lists the response length.
"/nonEtAk" is some non existing path and "/" is the existing one.

By comparing the response from non existing path with the existing one, I want to extract urls which are not giving false positive responses.
So I figure out that this can be done by comparing the response length.
So the data consists of that.
So where the domain is same i want to compare the second column and give the output as the domain.

e.g. in above `0-0.latam.corp.yahoo.com/`  is giving `6656` length and 
`0-0.latam.corp.yahoo.com/nonEtAk`  is giving `6670` length.
The difference is 14. So it is false positive.

While in case of `1.avatar.yahoo.com` the difference is 200+. So it has something interesting. So if I passed the above data, I want the result as `http://1.avatar.yahoo.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give a specific threshhold for acceptance so why not rank them by the difference

```
awk '{
  if ($1 ~ /nonEtAk/) {ss=substr($1,1,length($1)-7); rank[ss]+=$2} 
    else rank[$1]-=$2
  } END {
    for (key in rank) { print key, "difference is", rank[key] }
}' <(sed -e '/^$/d' file) | sort -r -k4
```

Output

```
http://1.avatar.yahoo.com/ difference is 214
http://0-0.latam.corp.yahoo.com/ difference is 14
```

Walkthrough

Remove all the empty lines and feed it to `awk`

```
awk '' <(sed -e '/^$/d' file)
```

In `awk`

If the first field contains "nonEtAk" then get the domain name substring (by chopping off the last 7 characters) and add the value from $2 to an associative array (rank) with the domain name as the key

```
if ($1 ~ /nonEtAk/) {ss=substr($1,1,length($1)-7); rank[ss]+=$2}
```

...otherwise subtract $2 from the array element with the domain name as the key

```
else rank[$1]-=$2
```

...when finished reading the file

```
`} END {`
```

...iterate over the array and print

```
for (key in rank) { print key, "difference is", rank[key] }
```

...finally rank them in descending order based upon the difference

```
| sort -r -k4
```

Comment: Wow!! This is really cool. It worked for me. When you are looking at a lot of domains close to 200K you cant do visual mapping effectively. But this one does the trick for filtering out the false positives.

Comment: Then you could always accept the answer..... ;-)